# matlab, Read multiple files .csv imported from a different directory

Tags: matlab, csv

I am having a problem when I try to read multiple csv files from another directory. here I will show two options of my code:

```
    clc;clear;
fileID = fopen('results.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID, 'Name\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%%variation\t\tSteady-state\n');
% s=dir('*.csv'); 
s=dir('C:\Users\michael\Documents\MATLAB\Data\*.csv');
for i = 1:length(s)
    s1= strsplit(s(i).name,'.'); %split string from csv
    s3 = char(strcat(s1(1),'.png'));%concatenate .png and convert to string

    a = csvread(s(i).name,1,0);
    ind = find(a(:,1)==60); %75% before end electrification
    ind2 = find(a(:,1)==(60-60*0.75));

    err = (a(ind,2)-a(ind2,2))/a(ind,2)*100; %variation

    fig=figure;
    plot(a(1:ind,1),a(1:ind,2),a(ind2:ind,1),a(ind2:ind,2),'*')
    xlabel('time [s]');ylabel('Volume resistivity [ohm.cm]');
    legend('y(x)', sprintf('variation = %0.1f%%',err),'Location','Southeast');
    saveas(fig,s3)
    for n = length(err)
        if err<5
        YoN = 'Yes';
        else
        YoN = 'No';
        end
    end
    fprintf(fileID, '%s\t\t%0.1f%%\t\t\t\t%s\n', s(i).name, err, YoN);
end

fclose(fileID);
```

Basically when i let all the csv files in the working directory and untoggle the comment s=dir('*.csv'), it works properly, when I try to open them from the different directory, it works until the line a=csvred(s(i).name,1,0).
At that point it says:

```
Error using csvread (line 35)
File not found.

Error in Untitled (line 10)
    a = csvread(s(i).name,1,0);
```

In both cases, s is a structure with 6 fields, and the field 'name' does exist in the structure.
Any suggestion?

Comment: The name is just the file name, MATLAB then looks within the current directory for that file, which doesn't exist like the error message says. You must do `a=csvred(['C:\Users\michael\Documents\MATLAB\Data\' s(i).name], 1,0)`

Comment: Thank you very much!

I will ask you 3 more things:
1) Is there a more legant way to make the tabulate spacing in the text that I am writing?
2)Is it possible to tell to matlab to look if the text file exist, if it doesn't to create one? If yes how?
3) How can I tell matlab to not open the figures it is creating? And how can I save them in a different directory (as before to create it if it doesn't exist)?

If you can ask to any of thes points it would be awesome.

Comment: 2. use a condition with the `exist` function, 3. `fig=figure('Visible','off')` will do the same in the figure, but you will not see it at all. `saveas(fig, ['C:\Users\Michael\somePath\' s3])` will save the figure in different directory. And a nice and stable way to do what @wolfie suggested is `a=csvread(fullfile(s(i).folder,s(i).name),1,0)`

Comment: Please do some of your own research, all 3 of those points have answers on this site, the documentation, or elsewhere. Questions here should be specific and show prior research, and not be asked in comments